# Reducing memory when manipulating images Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that downloads satellite imagery for helicopter landing sites and places them in to tabs with the site code. There are 166 to be exact each of those has 2 static map images for a total of 332 images and I need to manipulate them in several ways.

I have no issue downloading them and placing them but when I am manipulating them I run out of memory. The manipulations are to help our pilots see better at night when looking at the maps since they are displayed on a screen.

I typed out the following code and it works until about sheet 100 and then I run out of ram due to being restricted to a 32 bit Excel. is there a way to reduce the amount of memory being used?

```
Public Sub SwitchtoNight()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        With oWS
            .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0 'Saturation
            .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(1).Value = -0.35  'Brightness
            .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(2).Value = 0.75  'Contrast

            .Shapes("GoogleMap2").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0 'Saturation
            .Shapes("GoogleMap2").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(2).Value = 0.35  'Contrast
        End With
        Set oWS = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

The images are about 400px X 400px here is an example
[image]

With the following code I get to sheet 140 before I run out of ram

```
Public Sub SwitchtoNight()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        oWS.DisplayPageBreaks = False
        With oWS
            .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0: .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(1).Value = -0.35: .Shapes("GoogleMap1").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(2).Value = 0.75
            .Shapes("GoogleMap2").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0: .Shapes("GoogleMap2").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectBrightnessContrast).EffectParameters(2).Value = 0.35
        End With
        Set oWS = Nothing
    Next I

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How big are the pictures (in MB or resolution)?  Are you able to post a link to a sample picture? (It doesn't need to be of the actual site if that's an issue)  Is that the entire code? (or are you by chance opening/closing/manipulating Excel or any other applications programmatically?)

Comment: I added an example image I do not think they are large as my entire workbook with the 322 images is only 20mb large. and the images are 400 x 400

Comment: I am also not manipulating any programs. The excel sheet is opened fresh and is only using 70mb of ram before this code is run.

Comment: `PictureEffects.Insert` is basically adding layers on top of each image (as opposed to modifying the image) in such a way that each change is stored as a separate picture, that can later be "undone".  I assume your goal is to modify the image permanently?  Will these images be changing regularly or is this a one-off?

Comment: They don't change that often but I just figured out that I change the road map in the google api call for a night map that will work so that should reduce the modifications significantly

Comment: But once they are changed I shouldn't need to change them again unless we are redownloading the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the images as a Night Map will help, as will saving as JPG instead of PNG.  I think Excel just isn't meant to handle image manipulation on this scale, although saving, closing & re-opening partway through the process will free up some memory.

There are a number of free options (online or downloadable) for batch photo editing in this way, such as [ImBatch](http://www.highmotionsoftware.com/products/imbatch) or [BatchPhoto](https://www.batchphoto.com/espresso/), which will do the job in no time.

Note that PictureEffects is basically saving a new "layer" with each manipulation, sucking up memory along with it. (In my case, about 2000kb per change.)

If you do choose to stick with Excel, use the [ShapeRange.PictureFormat Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shaperange-pictureformat-property-excel) instead of the [PictureEffects Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/pictureeffects-object-office).

---

Also if you're using the API, note that Stack Overflow has a tag *just* for you!  [[image]google-static-maps](/questions/tagged/google-static-maps)  If you add that tag to your question, you might get further help from people more familiar with that API than I.

Check out this link (note the adjustments than can be handled directly in the URL):

> <sub>http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyADV4Wfi9-4ET5GG52Cw_l0_Bkt8W5vwvM&center=43.597586,-79.746689&zoom=14&markers=icon:http://www.xmeasures.com/images/planMapPin.png|43.597586,-79.746689&format=png32&sensor=false&size=480x480&scale=4&markers=color:black|&maptype=roadmap&style=feature|element:geometry|hue:0xwhite|saturation:-100%|lightness:100|visibility:off&style=feature:road|element:geometry|hue:0xblack|saturation:-100%|lightness:-20|visibility:on&style=feature:road.path|element:labels|hue:0xblack|saturation:-100%|lightness:-20|visibility:off&style=feature:labels|element:geometry|hue:0xblack|saturation:-100%|lightness:-20|visibility:off&style=feature:water|element:geometry|hue:0xblack|saturation:-100%|lightness:-40|visibility:on&style=element:labels.text.stroke|visibility:off&style=element:labels.text.fill|visibility:off&style=feature:road|hue:0xblack|saturation:-100%|lightness:-100|element:labels.text.fill|visibility:on&style=feature:transit|visibility:off&style=feature:poi|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape|visibility:off&key=AIzaSyADV4Wfi9-4ET5GG52Cw_l0_Bkt8W5vwvM|</sub>
>   ***([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434551/static-maps-list-of-features))***

---

Try something like:

```
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, sh As Shape
```

…

```
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(I)
    Set sh = oWS.Shapes("GoogleMap1")
    With sh
        .PictureFormat.Brightness = -0.35
        .PictureFormat.Contrast = 0.75

        With sh.Fill.PictureEffects
            .Delete (1)
            .Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0
        End With
    End With
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
```

…

I didn't test this but there are examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shaperange-pictureformat-property-excel) and [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?45621-set-color-saturation-of-image-with-vba&p=290984&viewfull=1#post290984)

Comment: I was able to adjust the static map api call with some from the google map designer which worked well but I could not get the ShapeRange.PictureFormat Property to change the picture

Comment: I added to my Answer above.

Comment: I ended up using the picture.format as the night map did not have building outlines :/ Picture.Format barely increases the memory usage from baseline so that is the correct method :)